# Are there words with positive connotations used to describe atheists or other non-religious people?

Tags: single-word-requests

Most words used to describe the lack of religion of people have negative connotations, for example:

> infidel, nonbeliever, disbeliever, unbeliever, skeptic, doubter, atheist, agnostic, heathen, heretic, nihilist, goy (Judaism), kaffir (Islam)

Many of these can also be applied to followers of other religions in addition to atheists.

Other words are at best neutral, for example:

> secularist, freethinker

Are there any words with positive connotations that can be used to describe non-religious people?

For example, for religious people, we have:

> holy, godly, pious, saintly, venerable, faithful

Comment: Well, there is "*Brights*", which was excoriated (or at least [heavily criticized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brights_movement#Criticism)) by the theistic community for being *too* positive an appellation (and by implication painting religious people as *dim*). Unfortunately it's mostly a proper noun (a name for *specific group* of secularists), and isn't popularly known in any case.

Comment: Not wishing to be *too* "anti-theistic", I can't see why people who don't believe in a deity should need a *positive* term to identify themselves, any more than people who don't believe the moon is made of green cheese. All the *negative* terms are specifically created and used by religious people, who obviously tend to have a negative opinion of those who don't share their faith (historically, such a bad opinion that they often take active steps to wipe out the non-believers).

Comment: @FumbleFingers As an atheist myself, I (like you said) don't find the need for a positive word to self-identify. I am mainly curious whether any exist.

Comment: But who would *use* it? Some "ultra-tolerant" religious person? I suppose by analogy we do now have the word ***straight*** to describe what once would have been just a "normal" person (with heterosexual orientation). But even in the UK today, the majority are religious, so we can't say being an atheist is "the norm", even though I'm sure the vast majority of them think of themselves as "normal", and the theists as the oddballs.

Comment: Worth mentioning that I don't feel that the specific words "*atheist*", "*agnostic*" or "*nonbeleiver*" are anything but descriptive and neutral. They generally *don't* carry value judgments; they were specifically introduced to be descriptive, without the baggage *infidel* et al carry. Of course, they *can* be used in a way paints them negatively, as any word can. In particular, when used by a religious  person for "someone who disagrees with my foundational beliefs", it's hard to avoid such a slant. (Which is incidentally why I think *goy* is not neutral despite the of my Jewish friends.)

Comment: @Dan: I don't think *atheist, agnostic, nonbeliever*, etc., are at all "neutral". To me, they're "loaded" in much the same way as *"Have you stopped beating your wife yet?"* Which you'd normally reject on the grounds that you've *never beaten* your wife. But analogising to the religious context, it's like asking that question of someone who's *not even married*. I haven't "lost my faith" - I never had it.

Comment: @Fumb I get what you're saying -- that these words, by their very construction, are "religio-normative" -- but I'm not sure I agree. I see them as simply *contrastive*, similar to *aerobic* vs *anaerobic* organisms; saying the latter are *without oxygen* is not implicitly stating that oxygen-breathing is the "standard": to the contrary, anaerobic organisms are significantly more populous than aerobic ones. I perfectly happy describing myself as an "atheist", as are many explicitly atheist organizations (but, like you, I think "organized atheism" is an oxymoron; I'm truly more of an apatheist).

Comment: @March Ho: Why do you say "freethinker" is "at best neutral"? It seems  positive to me.

Comment: Also, it should be pointed out that unlike agnosticism, *atheism* is a belief.  Atheism is the  belief that there is no Creator.  Science cannot measure anything before the Big Bang, and so it must refrain from making assertions about what might or might not have existed "before". To science, the "before" is unknowable. To me, that imperative translates to agnosticism, not to atheism. So the atheists and the theists are in the same boat of Belief.

Comment: @Dan: I've just finished watching Tyson's "redux" [*Cosmos*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2395695/) (even better than [*Sagan's original*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0081846/?ref_=fn_al_tt_2), which esriously impressed me at the time). Sometimes I despair when I reflect that most of the reasons why most people believe in their particular god boil down to the fact that they can't understand how their little world could come into existence (and be maintained thereafter) without supernatural intervention. But it's a *big* universe - why would Yahweh, for example, have created so many galaxies?

Comment: Maybe Yahweh had a LOT of free time.

Comment: @TimRomano "*Atheist*" is a broad term, and different people define it differently, oftentimes quite acrimonious^W contentiously. Suffice to say that one definition of "*atheism*" is "the positively-held belief that the statement '*there exists at least one deity*' is false", but another holds that "*atheism*" is a simple *absence* of belief in any deity, such as an infant has, or analogous to the lack of belief in unicorns, or that there is a teapot orbiting Mars. For me, personally, I think the total intractability of even *defining* the word "deity" renders all such debates moot.

Comment: @TimRomano I also agree "freethinker" is a positive term - in fact, that it was designed and purposefully introduced *to be* a positive term -- you might construct an answer along those lines.

Comment: I don't find Atheism intractable to define at all, and it's a very narrow term. Atheism is the belief that there is no Deity. If you want to add specious lingo about its being "positively held" and its relating to predications, or its being a pre-rational state comparable to the mind of an infant, well, that obfuscation is on you. The rational position that we cannot know whether there is or isn't a Deity is Agnosticism.

Comment: @TimRomano I didn't say "*atheism* is intractable to define", I said *deity* is intractable to define. If you don't believe me, try it yourself (well, ok, technically speaking,  the hard part is *getting everyone else* to agree with your definition ;). But if we want to explore this question seriously, we should probably do so on [Philosophy.se], not here in the comments on this question. So I'll bow out of the conversation now.

Comment: With this question you haven't defined what you mean by "positive" or "negative". For example, if you are a moderate person, the term "fundamentalist Christian" can be interpreted as "bad" because fundamentalism steps too far into dogma. OTOH, If you are a fundamentalist Christian, then the "fundamentalist" label speaks to the purity of your convictions and is good. So, what do you mean exactly by positive/negative. Positive/negative to who and with what measurement?

Comment: @TimRomano It seems at least nowadays atheists are pretty clear on how they use this term. I remember seeing a definition once that an atheist is "one who denies the existence of a deity" but this is clearly not what is meant now. Today people are using this word to mean "one who is not a theist and who does not have any particular religious convictions". For example, it would be ridiculous to call a Buddhist monk an "atheist" even if he does not happen to believe in a deity, and even if he really believes no such a deity can exist.

Comment: I've always regarded "freethinker" as having a negative cast to it, since I usually hear it used with "air quotes" by religious broadcasters.

Comment: @Tim Romano: The problem with saying "Atheism is the belief that there is no Deity" implies the prior existent of ***theists*** whom the atheist thinks are mistaken. But suppose one day we encounter aliens to whom the idea of a "sentient, interactive" god never even occurred? Once they'd mastered the subtleties of English, I'm sure they'd feel just as uncomfortable about calling themselves *atheists* as they would about being [self-]labelled *heathens, heretics, infidels,* etc.

Comment: Regarding what the word _atheism_ "really" means, the fact is, several subtly different meanings hover around the same word (pointed out in comments above), so if you want to be clear, you'll spell out explicitly which meaning you intend, in situations where the difference matters.

Comment: @FumbleFingers [Antiteapotists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_teapot) need no such term to make them stand out from all the gullible, credulous, superstitious, and irrational teapotists. Defining oneself in terms of what one does not believe seems to be coming at it the wrong way. Nonetheless, one can turn the tables by using terms like *evidence-based* and *rational* — or really any word that does not allow for gullible, etc. Let the man of reason be known as such to better distinguish him from men of unreason.

Comment: I've attempted to edit the question to remove *agnostic* from the list of of people who *refuse to have the wool pulled over their eyes*. To an agnostic there is no *wool* (@FumbleFingers); there is no such thing as "marriage".

Comment: @tchrist: I resent being labelled a Roman Catholic just because [I'm a BigEndian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Etymology). If the boiled egg doesn't fit nicely, use a different eggcup - don't commit the sacrilege of cracking the wrong end! :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Given the nature of this particular subject matter it’s difficult for me to conceive of any term describing a lack of theistic belief which would not carry some negative or disparaging connotation for one who professes theistic or religious belief. In like manner, any term describing theistic or religious belief would tend to have a negative or uncomplimentary connotation for those who find such professions “unreasonable.”

That said, for me, the term “rationalism” and the related noun “rationalist,” are as neutral or *non*-disparaging as is conceivable.

> **rationalism** *noun*
>
> 1. A belief or theory that opinions and actions should be based on reason and knowledge rather than on religious belief or emotional response:
>    “scientific rationalism.” see Oxford Dictinaries [**rationalism**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/rationalism)

Comment: I like this term, Little Eva. It reveals how rational human minds can bend identical data toward contrary conclusions. The vast majority of people consider transcendent knowledge to be the rational inference of empirical data--like accepting the existence of [quarks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark), though they are much too small to observe directly with current technology. So it has the added advantage of keeping epistemological conversations open.

Comment: _Rationalist_ might be the best choice, but it also carries meanings that might be the opposite of what you intend. For example, rationalism as opposed to empiricism is the theory that all valid knowledge derives from the mind alone, without regard to experience. In other words, rationalism is the belief that knowledge is innate or somehow transcendent. Plato and Descartes (a theist, on the basis of rationalistic deductions) are the prototypical examples. Noam Chomsky adheres to rationalism in a subtly different sense: he means that language-learning ability transcends experience.

Comment: @Ben - yes, thank you, and well-put. I only offer "rationalism" *after* my preface, and then *only* in the sense taken from OD *online*.

Comment: I don't call myself a rationalist even though I'm an atheist because _rationalist_ even in the "science is good" sense seems to me to have acquired a negative connotation. Many who call themselves "rationalists" are referring to their adherence to an extremely rigid, quasi-legalistic style of reasoning and especially arguing, which excludes the looseness and complexity of a genuinely reasonable attitude. I don't think I'm alone among atheists in rolling my eyes when I hear someone claim to be a "rationalist". The inward reaction: "Oh no, another one of those argumentative twits."

Comment: @LittleEva Indeed, any choice of word here is going to involve a trade-off. If we rejected words because they had unwanted senses or ambiguities, we would never speak at all. And actually, the word's primary sense, orientation by reason (_rational_ being the adjective for _reason_), has a positive connotation. Notice that _[irrationalism](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/99591)_ has a strong negative connotation, even though some people openly declare for it.

Answer (score 5):

> Are there any words with positive connotations that can be used to
>   describe non-religious people?

These people could describe themselves as *[Empiricists](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/empiricist)*:

> noun
>
> A person who supports the theory that all knowledge is based on
>   experience derived from the senses:

Since the fundamental dispute between *agnostics* and *religionists* is about the veracity of knowledge that transcends scientific observation, it makes sense for *agnostics* to define themselves at the cutting edge of the discussion.

***Empiricists*** challenge the transcendent notion of God.

Comment: +1. However, although this is a good answer, I feel that it still does not have as much of a positive connotation as "rationalist".

Comment: @Margan Horse  -  Careful, in Marxism, empiricist has a not very nice connotation.  I vaguely remember it had to do with doing bad science -- creating experimental evidence to support the position you had before you started the experiment -- if I remember right.

Comment: It is true, @aparente001; with such a diverse group speaking English, we have very little hope of finding a word that has **purely** positive connotations.

Answer (score 3):

***Humanist*** is a term used by some.

*[Humanism](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/humanism)*:

> - a system of values and beliefs that is based on the idea that people are basically good and that problems can be solved using reason instead of religion. (M-W)

Comment: I can't go with this, because ***humanist*** implies subscribing to *any system of thought or ideology which places humans, or humanity as a whole, at its centre, esp. one which is predominantly concerned with human interests and welfare, and stresses the inherent value and potential of human life* (OED). Just because someone doesn't believe in a personified deity doesn't mean he has a "god-sized hole" that needs to be filled by "humanity".

Comment: +1 I understand @FumbleFingers's analysis of agnosticisms deeper motivations, but *humanist* has generally positive connotations, and it does describe a popular worldview sans transcendent beings. It would be good to realize that in the minds of **some** religious folks, the tag carries mixed baggage: + for elevating mankind - for marginalizing God. As a man with faith in worlds beyond our wildest imagination, I believe that it is healthy for all people to define their stands in positive terms.

Comment: Isn't the historically accepted term '_secular_ humanist'? Which supposedly is a positive name for those in the group but cause for spitting by those outside, (just like 'fundamentalist').

Comment: The first iteration of the [Humanist Manifesto](http://americanhumanist.org/Humanism/Humanist_Manifesto_I) is secular in nature as well as it subsequent iterations. The word *Secular* was added by religious folks to distinguish from [Christian Humanism](http://www.newworldencyclopedia.org/entry/Christian_Humanism).

Comment: The most common argument I hear from religious people with a burning desire to convert me is that if I raise my children without inculcating a belief in god, they will grow up valueless.  I think that's why "humanist" and "humanistic" are popular -- they show that we have separated out the teaching of values from the other, irrational stuff.  However, if I forget for the moment about protecting myself from the folks who itch to convert me to their religion, and think only about my own motivation for rejecting religion, it's to give myself back my self-determinism (as opposed to praying). cont.

Comment: part 2:  The first time I went to a Humanistic Judaism gathering, one of the people there explained the group by saying, "this is a way of being Jewish without any prayers."  I cried, out of relief that I could give my children a Jewish identity without qualms.  -  So I will propose "humanistic" or "self-determinist".  -  By the way, the thing that drives me really nuts nowadays is the phrase "Everything happens for a reason."  It's so sanctimonious, and subversive.  I'd rather the people who say that put their God-determinist beliefs out in the open.

Answer (score -1):

Admittedly with malice aforethought, I have been known to describe myself as **'godless'**. The fun thing about this term is that it takes a frequent insult of religious people and wears it as a badge of pride (cf 'queer'). Oh, and it lets me say that I have a godlessdaughter in Chicago....

Comment: It seems this kind of co-opting is an attempt to **create** positive connotations rather than to employ them.

Comment: @GoodA.M. doesn't seem like that much of a stretch to me. Supposing you by god you mean a being who is broadly responsible for the state of the world, godlessness might seem a positive advantage - just as to a gay person with normal levels of self-esteem, any label for their orientation would obviously have some positive connotations from their perspective, regardless of whether it was originally intended as an insult.

Comment: @DavidPugh, Yes, godlessdaughter is cute.

Answer (score -4):

'pagan' or 'irreligionist' are positive connotations - as soon as one realizes, that religions are bad for mankind: they bring war and death.

btw: what's bad about animals? they don't have any gods, and we are all animals, too. therefore, i see no reason to put anything negative into the words who are describing a antheist

Comment: [Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pagan) seems to support a highly negative connotation for "pagan". "<the Spanish conquistadores regarded the native peoples of the lands that they conquered as pagans who were uncivilized and inherently inferior>"

Comment: I also fail to understand the "animal" comment. I did not mention anything about animals (or animism for that matter) in my question.

Comment: the 'animal' comment is ment to say: we are all animals, thus, why should non-believing be a bad thing, even thought the mentioned definitions are suggesting a negative coonotation? this is defently not true if you see what religions and believing is all about!

Comment: In my experience, *all* human institutions---not merely those of a religious orientation---inevitably become invested in the accumulation of power and self-perpetuation and, therefore, war and it's correlate, death.

Comment: I think the negative connotation of "pagan" is historical. But since paganism is now a religion (or a group of religions, some ancient and some modern), it doesn't answer the OP's request for a word describing non-religious people whatever connotations it has.

Comment: This is completely wrong. [Paganism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paganism) refers to a very wide group of religions and religious beliefs.